# AX 2012 R2 CU7 AIF: Failed to add a service

Tags: service, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, wcftestclient, aif

I've created an HTTP inbound port. I'm able to access the services using Visual Studio. However, when I try to add the service to the wcfTestClient, I get the following error:

> **Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.
>   c:\Users\firstname.lastname\AppData\Local\Temp\Test Client
>   Projects\10.0\45eaacda-a1b6-4b95-be46-7634658b8393\Client.cs(508,73) :
>   error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Application' does not exist
>   in the namespace 'Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)**

Any ideas on what might be causing the issue or where I can look to find out more information.

Thank you.

Comment: *WcfTestClient* obviously does not support all the object structures or there is an error/bogus schema definition within the WSDL.

For example it works with the standard *SharedServices* (`http://localhost:8101/DynamicsAx/Services/SharedServices`), but does not work with standard *UserSessionService* (`http://localhost:8101/DynamicsAx/Services/UserSessionService`).

Just make new *Console Application* within Visual Studio, add service reference and create simple test code. Or you can give a try some other SOAP testing tool.

Comment: We were able to test with WcfTestClient previously. Now, we can't. We are trying to identify what caused the issue.

Comment: Have you added some `Enum`s to the service? AIF generates all the Enums into the wsdl. Inspect wsdl manually. Use `?singleWsdl` at the end to reqest all-in-one wsdl.

Comment: @Matej, Thanks for your response. Yes, you are correct. I'd added a custom base enum to my custom service class. When I try with singleWsdl, I get teh following message in wcfTestCient:Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://myServer/MicrosoftDynamicsAXAif60/xyzDevPoHttp01/xppservice.svc?singlewsdl 
If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  
For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455

Comment: Additional info: Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://myServer/MicrosoftDynamicsAXAif60/xyzDevPoHttp01/xppservice.svc?singlewsdl'.    
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.